# Rails: Form inputs not saving after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphic-associations, actionview, actioncontroller

why wont anything entered into this form save?

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@requestable, @request] do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :status %>
   <%= f.text_field :status, rows: 8 %>
   <%= f.submit "Request", :class => 'btn'%>
<% end %>
```

requests_controller.rb

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :load_requestable

   def index
     @requests = @requestable.requests
   end

   def new
     @request = @requestable.requests.new
   end

   def create
     @request = @requestable.requests.new(params[:status])
     if @request.save
        redirect_to [@requestable, :requests], notice: "Request sent."
     else
      render :new
   end
 end

private

  def load_requestable
    klass = [Company, Profile].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"]}
    @requestable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
  end

end
```

my controller is based on this
https://github.com/railscasts/154-polymorphic-association-revised/blob/master/blog-after/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

request.rb
    class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  attr_accessible :status

  belongs_to :requestable , polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :profile

  validates :status,  presence: true

end
```

This is being produced by my debuger

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: /0H2k89HN4JVXBPsoFWen5rUfx2xr4p5hr1uDSQVlcA=
request: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  status: pending
commit: Request
action: create
controller: requests
company_id: '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what's in your params hash. The status field is probably in something like `params[:request][:status]`. Assuming standard activerecord-y stuff, you want to pass the hash for the whole request object to .new.

Comment: Just tried that it didn't change anything. I'ved added a link to the controller that I based my coded on.

Comment: Please take a look at what's in the params hash after posting the form. You need to answer these questions: Does the information get from the form into the params hash? Does it get from the params hash into the new Request object? Does it get from the new Request object into the database?

Comment: I have added debugger output. I can get all this to work in the console, so I'm leaning towards the form isn't passing the information to the params hash.

Comment: It's in there, in the 4th and 5th lines. So the thing to pass to .new is params[:request] (although you might like to verify that that hash contains { status: 'pending' } first)

Comment: that did the trick, but I don't understand why? how does the params[:request] know too pull :status?

Comment: Well, the value params[:request] is a hash that includes status. It doesn't know how to pull :status, per se. The trick here is that ActiveRecord's mass assignment methods (new, update_attributes, etc) accept hashes and grab values from those hashes for everything in the attr_accessible list.